# how to show a specific field in array using $project in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database that contains information about flights. I'm trying to find the category that has the least minutes of delays. I managed to find and show the number of the minimum minutes of the category but not the category itself.

I've tried to put ":true" after each field to show it

```
db.delayData.aggregate([{
                $group: {
                    "_id": "$carrier",
                    "arr_sum": {
                        $sum: "$arr_delay"
                    },
                    "carrier_sum": {
                        $sum: "$carrier_delay"
                    },
                    "weather_sum": {
                        $sum: "$weather_delay"
                    },
                    "nas_sum": {
                        $sum: "$nas_delay"
                    },
                    "sec_sum": {
                        $sum: "$security_delay"
                    },
                    "late_air_sum": {
                        $sum: "$late_aircraft_delay"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $project {
                    "min_delay_category": {
                        $min["$arr_sum", "$carrier_sum", "$weather_sum", "$nas_sum", "$sec_sum", "$late_air_sum"]
                    }
                }
            ]).pretty()
```

I want to have something like that:
    { "_id" : "VX", "min_delay_category" : 1449, "sec_sum"... }

I've tried to write:

```
     ..."$sec_sum":1,"$late_air_sum":1]
```

but the error message is:

```
     "missing ] after element list"
```

when I wrote:

```
      ...{"sec_sum":1},{"late_air_sum":1}]
```

I don't have error message but it will give me the least second result, not the first one.
for example:

```
      { "_id" : "VX", "min_delay_category" : 69081 }
```

but the true result for "VX" is 1449

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The expected output is not clear. Can you please post sample data and proper expected output.

Comment: There are categories  of delays: carrier_delay- total minutes of delays due to carrier. weather_delay-total minutes of delays due to weather, and  4 more: arr_delay, nas_delay, security delay, late_aircraft_delay.  The id represents the airline code (carrier). For each airline I have lots of flights. I need to sum the delays in each category to find out which category for each airline has the least minutes of delays. The expected output is:  { "_id" : "VX", category: security_delay , "min_delay_category" : 1449 } or:  { "_id" : "VX" , "min_delay_category" : security_delay }.

Comment: okay. If you can please post a sample document, it would help to prepare a perfect query.

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("5d5b5058435c7584459b7bae"), "year" : 2003, "month" : 6, "carrier" : "AA", "carrier_name" : "American Airlines Inc.", "airport" : "ABQ", "airport_name" : "Albuquerque, NM: Albuquerque International Sunport", "arr_flights" : 307, "arr_del15" : 56, "carrier_ct" : 14.68, "weather_ct" : 10.79, "nas_ct" : 19.09, "security_ct" : 1.48, "late_aircraft_ct" : 9.96, "arr_cancelled" : 1, "arr_diverted" : 1, "arr_delay" : 2530, "carrier_delay" : 510, "weather_delay" : 621, "nas_delay" : 676, "security_delay" : 25, "late_aircraft_delay" : 698, "" : "" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            "carrier":1,
            "category.arr_delay":"$arr_delay",
            "category.carrier_delay":"$carrier_delay",
            "category.weather_delay":"$weather_delay",
            "category.nas_delay":"$nas_delay",
            "category.security_delay":"$security_delay",
            "category.late_aircraft_delay":"$late_aircraft_delay"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "carrier":1,
            "categories":{
                $objectToArray:"$category"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$categories"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "carrier":"$carrier",
                "category":"$categories.k"
            },
            "carrier":{
                $first:"$carrier"
            },
            "category":{
                $first:"$categories.k"
            },
            "total_delay":{
                $sum:"$categories.v"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            "total_delay":1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id": "$carrier",
            "carrier":{
                $first:"$carrier"
            },
            "category":{
                $first:"$category"
            },
            "minimum_delay":{
                $first:"$total_delay"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty();
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5b5058435c7584459b7bae"),
    "year" : 2003,
    "month" : 6,
    "carrier" : "AA",
    "carrier_name" : "American Airlines Inc.",
    "airport" : "ABQ",
    "airport_name" : "Albuquerque, NM: Albuquerque International Sunport",
    "arr_flights" : 307,
    "arr_del15" : 56,
    "carrier_ct" : 14.68,
    "weather_ct" : 10.79,
    "nas_ct" : 19.09,
    "security_ct" : 1.48,
    "late_aircraft_ct" : 9.96,
    "arr_cancelled" : 1,
    "arr_diverted" : 1,
    "arr_delay" : 2530,
    "carrier_delay" : 510,
    "weather_delay" : 621,
    "nas_delay" : 676,
    "security_delay" : 25,
    "late_aircraft_delay" : 698,
    "" : ""
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5b5058435c7584459b7bbe"),
    "year" : 2003,
    "month" : 6,
    "carrier" : "AA",
    "carrier_name" : "American Airlines Inc.",
    "airport" : "ABQ",
    "airport_name" : "Albuquerque, NM: Albuquerque International Sunport",
    "arr_flights" : 307,
    "arr_del15" : 56,
    "carrier_ct" : 14.68,
    "weather_ct" : 10.79,
    "nas_ct" : 19.09,
    "security_ct" : 1.48,
    "late_aircraft_ct" : 9.96,
    "arr_cancelled" : 1,
    "arr_diverted" : 1,
    "arr_delay" : 2530,
    "carrier_delay" : 510,
    "weather_delay" : 621,
    "nas_delay" : 676,
    "security_delay" : 2512,
    "late_aircraft_delay" : 698,
    "" : ""
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "carrier" : "AA", "category" : "carrier_delay", "minimum_delay" : 1020 }
```

**Aggregation stage details:**

- **STAGE I:** Projecting all delays as a part of `category` document
- **STAGE II:** Converting `category` into an array of key-value pair
  where 'k' is delay type and 'v' is a delay
- **STAGE III:** Unwinding the prepared array
- **STAGE IV:** Grouping on the basis of `carrier` and `delay type(k)` and summing up delay for each type
- **STAGE V:** Sorting on total calculated delay in ascending order
- **STAGE VI:** Grouping on `carrier` and fetching the first document
  which holds the minimum delay